# Conditional Comments don't seem to be working in Outlook 2016

Tags: outlook

We have used conditional commenting in our blast emails to hide visual elements incompatible with Outlook while displaying elements that are compatible.

Recently, in Outlook 2016, this capability doesn't seem to be working anymore.

I've attached an image of sample code, as well as how it renders in Outlook 2016. You'll notice the text that should appear in Outlook isn't.

Has Conditional Commenting support been removed from Outlook?

A screenshot of the conditional comment when viewing source, and how it is not showing up in Outlook.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try it without gaps in code:

**Target Outlook**:

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/ff0000?text=Outlook" alt="" width="100%" style="display:inline-block;border:none;outline:none;padding:0;margin:0;width:100%;height:auto;" border="0" hspace="0" vspace="0">
<![endif]-->
```

**Hide from Outlook**:

```
<!--[if !mso]><!-- -->
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/0000ff/?text=Modern+Email" alt="Modern+Email" width="100%" style="display:inline-block;border:none;outline:none;padding:0;margin:0;width:100%;height:auto;" border="0" hspace="0" vspace="0">
<!--<![endif]-->
```

- https://jsfiddle.net/wallyglenn/5hruzos5/

Good luck.

Comment: Wow thanks! Apparently our visual HTML editing component (tinymce) was messing with the conditional formatting tags, adding a space. I've added a corrector in our post save processing.